# Laravel : Join two tables get the info from table one and get the first related image from table two

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two table one is `propertyDetails` and the other is `propertyImages`
and I have done the relation between the two tables like so..

here is the models

**propertyDetails**

```
class PropertyDetail extends \Eloquent {
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function propImages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('PropertyImage', 'property_details_id');
    }
}
```

**Table migration**

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('property_details', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->enum('purpose', array('Sell', 'Rent'));
            $table->integer('property_owner_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('property_agent_id')->nullable();
            $table->integer('bedroom');
            $table->integer('dining_room');
            $table->integer('bathroom');
            $table->string('title', 100);
            $table->integer('price');
            $table->string('type', 120);
            $table->string('specify_type', 120);
            $table->text('details');
            $table->integer('active');
            $table->foreign('property_owner_id')->references('id')->on('property_owners')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**propertyImages**

```
class PropertyImage extends \Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = [];

    public function propertyImages()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('PropertyDetail', 'property_details_id');
    }
}
```

**Table migration**

```
Schema::create('property_images', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('property_details_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('property_details_id')->references('id')->on('property_details')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->binary('image');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

what I want to do is select all the `projectsDetails` with the first related image from table two `propertyImages`

I tried

```
$properties = PropertyDetail::with('propImages')->get();
return View::make('admin.properties.view', compact('properties'));
```

and in my view

```
@foreach($properties as $property)
{{ HTML::image('images/propertyImages/'.$property->propImages->image, $property->title, array('width'=>767, 'height'=>384)) }}
@endforeach
```

got

> Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all here is how I got it to work

in the view section as @Ferran suggested I did this

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)
  // access property properties here
  @foreach ($property->image as $image)
    // access image properties here.
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

but because I need only the first image and not all I found the solution [here](https://gist.github.com/ericbarnes/5771365)

I just changed the second `@foreach` to use `slice`
here is the final code

```
@foreach ($properties as $property)
      // access property properties here
      @foreach($property->propImages->slice(0, 1) as $image)
        // access image properties here.
      @endforeach
    @endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error says, you're trying to get a relationship on a collection, the relationship exists on the objects (records) in that collection. You need to loop over the Properties, and for each one get their items...

```
 @foreach ($properties as $property)
  // access property properties here
  @foreach ($property->image as $image)
    // access image properties here.
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: nice you got my issue correct, but just one thing last I need to get the first image only not all

Comment: You can change your ->get() to ->first()

Comment: I don't think so because I am querying  the `properties` not the `images` the question is how to brake after the first loop of images

Answer (score 0):

Change this line:

```
return View::make('admin.properties.view', compact('properties'));
```

to

```
return View::make('admin.properties.view', ['properties' => $properties]));
```

and try again.

**Note:** The second argument passed to View::make is an array of data that should be made available to the view.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#views)

Comment: Mayank Pandeyz same thing noting changed same error, I event just try this `$properties = PropertyDetail::with(['propImages' => function($query){
            $query->where('property_details_id', 'id');
        }])->get();`
and still the same results

Comment: about the Note: my view looks like that `@foreach($properties as $property)
{{ HTML::image('images/propertyImages/'.$property->propImages->image, $property->title, array('width'=>767, 'height'=>384)) }}
@endforeach`